# Unity - WebGL build works fine into the localhost but not into the webserver

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, localhost, webgl

I wanted to create a WebGL game with Unity. So i created my version of the game, i built it and works just fine in the localhost that unity launches after the build, but when i upload it in my web server, the game and the debug tool of chrome give me the following errors:

[image: Game's error]
[image: Browser's console error]

Answer (score 1):

What helped me was changing compression format to Gzip and enabling Decompression fallback.
[webgl publishing setting picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2Mym.png)

Answer (score 0):

`build > preferences > publish settings`

Check your decompression settings. Sites like itch.io don't support Brotli compression, so you'll have to set it to fallback. If that doesn't work, try disabling the decompressions settings.

[See more](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-deploying.html)

Comment: the brotli and gzip compression still gives error onto the creeen. I set the compression to disabled the game doesn't give any errror but the console says:

wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': Incorrect response MIME type. Expected 'application/wasm'

Comment: You could try adding                 <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="\.unityweb$" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="\.wasm$" />         to your outbound rules condition. I don't have much experience on the web server side, so take that as you will